# mk-heartbeat issue in mysql replication setup

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication

I am facing problem in setting mysql replication monitoring using mk-heartbeat.

```
DBI connect('Heartbeat;host=10.160.251.223;mysql_read_default_group=client','heartbeat',...) failed: Access denied for user 'heartbeat'@'%' to database 'Heartbeat' at /EBSroot/maatkit/mk-heartbeat line 2056
```

I have created a user heartbeat that has no permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this document http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-heartbeat.html 
Also Access denied error is because of invalid credentials. Check MySQL username and password are correct on both server (Master and slave) and run application by referring to documentation provided.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use mysql shell command to check if the username or password is ok
for example : 
mysql -u heartbeat -p -h 10.160.251.223, and just enter if you don't have password...

by the way, I suggest adding a password for this user for security.